# Is there an alternative to a bunch of dom-if's in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to show an element based on an object type. For example, if the object type is 'string', `paper-input` should be displayed; if the type is 'boolean', `paper-radio-group` should be displayed, etc.

Below is a snippet of the component template.

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{_isStringInput(question.input_type)}}">
   <paper-input name="{{question.id}}" label="{{question.sort}}. {{question.text}}" always-float-label placeholder="{{question.help}}" required="{{question.required}}" error-message="Required" class="{{_isRequiredClass(question.required)}}"></paper-input>
</template>

<template is="dom-if" if="{{_isBooleanInput(question.input_type)}}">
   <label>{{question.sort}}. {{question.text}}</label>
   <paper-radio-group selected="" name="{{question.id}}" attr-for-selected="value" data-required="{{question.required}}">
      <paper-radio-button name="{{question.id}}" value="yes">Yes</paper-radio-button>
      <paper-radio-button name="{{question.id}}" value="no">No</paper-radio-button>
      <p class="radio-error-message">Required</p>
   </paper-radio-group>
</template>
```

As you can imagine, if I were to check for more types ('int', 'date', 'email', etc.), the `dom-if` list could grow bigger and bigger.

Is there a better/more elegant way to do this without a bunch of `dom-if` templates? (I'm thinking about something switch case vs. a bunch of if-else-ifs, but in Polymer)

Answer (score 1):

I think these are the closest thing that Polymer has for that.

[Dom-else](https://github.com/Trakkasure/dom-else)

[Dom-if-else](https://github.com/Trakkasure/dom-if-else)

Can't find any `if-else-if`.

[Here](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2165) is an open enhancement issue on Github. Don't expect any such change from Polymer soon.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind elements being just hidden instead of destroyed (which is opt-in with `dom-if` anyway), you can use CSS or `hidden` attribute to toggle visibility of your DOM

#### Using CSS classes to hide elements

The `toggle` function may be a little clunky but that's how you have to toggle using class. See below for an example with attributes.

```js
Polymer({
  is: 'toggle-element',
    
  toggle: function() {
    if(!this.disabled) {
      this.disabled = 'disabled';
    } else {
      this.disabled = null;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/" />
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import" />
</head>

<body>
  <toggle-element></toggle-element>

  <dom-module id="toggle-element">
    <template>
      <style>
        .disabled {
          display: none;
        }
      </style>
      
      <button on-tap="toggle">Click to toggle</button>
      <div class$="{{disabled}}">this will toggle</div>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

#### Using `hidden` attribute

This is a cleaner option but will work only with boolean properties.

```js
Polymer({
  is: 'toggle-element',
    
  toggle: function() {
    this.disabled = !this.disabled;
  } 
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/" />
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import" />
</head>

<body>
  <toggle-element></toggle-element>

  <dom-module id="toggle-element">
    <template>          
      <button on-tap="toggle">Click to toggle</button>
      <div hidden$="{{disabled}}">this will toggle</div>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

#### Using attributes and CSS to hide elements

Similar to the above but with attribute selector you can do anything that is possible with CSS and not being limited to hiding only (come think of it now, you can also style the `hidden` property, which Polymer uses by default. The principle is the same)

```js
Polymer({
  is: 'toggle-element',
    
  toggle: function() {
    this.disabled = !this.disabled;
  } 
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/" />
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import" />
</head>

<body>
  <toggle-element></toggle-element>

  <dom-module id="toggle-element">
    <template>
      <style>
        [disabled] {
          display: none;
        }

        div:not([disabled]) {
          color: green;
        }
      </style>
      
      <button on-tap="toggle">Click to toggle</button>
      <div disabled$="{{disabled}}">this will toggle</div>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```